Execution of SQL Script statement
I hope you are fine and doing well. At this time I'm developing my RESTful API web service application. I use h2 console temporary db storage and works well.
I face a challenge on execution of an SQL Script statement named data.sql which I put in the path src/main/resources/data.sql
When I try to run my application on Intellij the following errors occurred,
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "INGREDIENTS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:

insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME) values (0.1, 500001, 'Water') [42104-224]

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of file [E:\Educational\Software Engineering\Spring Boot\Exercises\Training\My-Cafe-Restful-Webservice\target\classes\data.sql]: insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME) values (0.1, 500001, 'Water')

How can I handle the issue? Waiting for your response.
Sincereley,
the script is
--INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE  INGREDIENT_ID  INGREDIENT_NAME -> ingredients

insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME)

values (0.1, 500001, 'Water');



insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME)

values (0.5, 500002, 'Flour');



insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME)

values (0.3, 500003, 'Oil');



insert into INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_BASE_PRICE, INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_NAME)

values (0.3, 500004, 'Sugar');



--PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_PRICE  PRODUCT_WEIGHT_GRAMS  PRODUCT_NAME   -> products



insert into PRODUCTS (PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_PRICE, PRODUCT_WEIGHT_GRAMS, PRODUCT_NAME)

values (10001, 18.5, 80.0, 'Donat');



--INGREDIENT_INGREDIENT_ID  INGREDIENT_WEIGHT  PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID   -> product_ingredients



insert into PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_WEIGHT, PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID)

values ( 500001, 50.0, 10001);



insert into PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_WEIGHT, PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID)

values ( 500002, 5.0, 10001);



insert into PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_WEIGHT, PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID)

values ( 500003, 10.0, 10001);



insert into PRODUCT_INGREDIENTS (INGREDIENT_INGREDIENT_ID, INGREDIENT_WEIGHT, PRODUCT_PRODUCT_ID)

values ( 500004, 5.0, 10001);

I expect to observe those data in my h2 console, unfortunately I can't.

From the error message it seems the INGREDIENTS table doesn't exist. What is the question exactly?
